# How can I get WWW-Mechanize to login to Wells Fargo's website?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I am trying to use Perl's [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize) to login to my bank and pull transaction information. After logging in through a browser to my bank (Wells Fargo), it briefly displays a temporary web page saying something along the lines of "please wait while we verify your identity". After a few seconds it proceeds to the bank's webpage where I can get my bank data. The only difference is that the URL contains several more "GET" parameters appended to the URL of the temporary page, which only had a sessionID parameter.

I was able to successfully get WWW::Mechanize to login from the login page, but it gets stuck on the temporary page. There is a `<meta http-equiv="Refresh"`... tag in the header, so I tried `$mech->follow_meta_redirect` but it didn't get me past that temporary page either.

Any help to get past this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the barebones code that gets me stuck at the temporary page:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->agent_alias( 'Linux Mozilla' );

$mech->get( "https://www.wellsfargo.com" );
$mech->submit_form(
    form_number => 2,
    fields => {
        userid => "$userid",
        password => "$password"
    },
    button => "btnSignon"
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, it has been years since I've coded Perl. However, since there's no "copy and paste" answer posted for this question yet, here's how to scrape Wells Fargo in Ruby:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

username = 'your_username'
password = 'your_password'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows IE 6'

# get first page
page = agent.get('https://online.wellsfargo.com/signon/')

# find and fill form
form = page.form_with(:name => 'Signon')      
form['userid'] = username
form['password'] = password
page = agent.submit form

# find the refresh url
page.body.match /content="1;URL=(.*?)"/
nexturl = $1

# wait a little while and then get the next page
sleep 3
page = agent.get nexturl

# If you have multiple accounts, you can use this. If you just have a single account, you can remove this block
companies = [['Account1', '123456789'], 
             ['Account2', '123456789']]

companies.each do |name, id|
  form = page.form_with(:name => 'ChangeViewFormBean')
  form['viewKey'] = id
  page = agent.submit form

  available_balance = page.search("#cashTotalAvailBalance").text.strip

  puts "#{name}: #{available_balance}"
  sleep 2
end
```

Works Cited: There's a guy who wrote a version of this script, posted it to his code directory and then forwarded the whole thing to his blog. His last name is Youngblood or similar. I found the source in the internet archive/way back machine and modified it to make what you see above. So, thanks Mr. Youngblood or similar, where ever you are - and thanks for teaching me the meta scrape trick!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to reverse-engineer what's happening on that intermediary page. Does it use Javascript to set some cookies, for example? Mech won't parse or execute Javascript on a page, so it may be trying to follow the meta-refresh but missing some crucial information about what needs to happen for the final request.

Try using a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to watch the request that's sent when the browser follows the meta-refresh. Examine all the request headers, including cookies, that are sent to request the final page. Then use Mech to duplicate that.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to Firebug. I installed it and noted there is a `<body id="wf_wellsfargo_com" onload="getPrefs();addFlash()">` line in the intermediary page that refers to a javascript function. I'm guessing I'm out of luck since Mech can't deal with javascript at this point.

Comment: You may not be out of luck, you just need to find out what those Javascript functions are doing and make Mech do the same thing. Use Firebug to watch the HTTP transaction -- are there any POST fields or cookies that you didn't see before? The JS probably added them, so add the same things with Mech.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the location of the next page you can try getting it after attaching the extra get parameters using

```
$mech->add_header($name => $value);
```

Comment: That will add a request header, but not add fields to the request URI or POST content.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know is this Javascript or not: i recommend to use [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) (but you may use [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/722) too) to disable Javascript and try to login via browser (but **first you need to clear all cookies related to your target site!**).

If you **still (with Javascript disabled) can login** than **this is not Javascript issue** and you need to investigate HTTP headers (it may be x,y coordinates of the clicked button for example or some cookies recieved only when you load CSS file etc).

I recommend to use [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647/) for checking HTTP headers. You need to run HttpFox logging and after that perform login again (by the way disabling images before doing this will significantly reduce your log). After that you need to check every request and corresponding response to find where hidden cookies are setted or some hidden form param created.

If you can not login after disabling Javascript than you need to look at the headers too. You need to compare cookies provided in HTTP header response with cookies you have in the later request. After you find html with "malicious" Javascript you can analize this Javascript to find algorithm how this cookie (or form param) created.

And you last step will be to **repeat this cookie/form param in you WWW::Mechanize request**.

Comment: ! Most answers usually provide copy/paste answers, you provide the general logic behind the process! Thanx